# TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'encoding'

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

```
from nltk.tag.stanford import CoreNLPNERTagger as POSTagger
english_postagger = POSTagger(RESOURCES_DIR+'jars/english-left3words-distsim.tagger',RESOURCES_DIR+'jars/stanford-postagger.jar', encoding='utf-8')
```

When I run the above code, I got the following error. How to solve this issue?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "ILPMod.py", line 44, in <module>
 english_postagger = POSTagger(RESOURCES_DIR+'jars/english-left3words-distsim.tagger',RESOURCES_DIR+'jars/stanford-postagger.jar', encoding='utf-8')
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'encoding'
```

Answer (score 1):

[`CoreNLPNERTagger`](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#nltk.tag.stanford.CoreNLPNERTagger) that you've imported as `POSTagger` has a different interface than [`StanfordPOSTagger`](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#nltk.tag.stanford.StanfordPOSTagger). From the documentation:

> `class nltk.tag.stanford.CoreNLPNERTagger(url='http://localhost:9000',
>                                           encoding='utf8')`
>
> Bases: `nltk.tag.stanford.CoreNLPTagger`
>
> This is a subclass of the CoreNLPTagger that wraps around the
>   `nltk.parse.CoreNLPParser` for Named-Entity tagging.
>
> ```
> >>> from nltk.tag.stanford import CoreNLPNERTagger
> >>> CoreNLPNERTagger(url='http://localhost:9000').tag('Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY'.split())  [('Rami', 'PERSON'),('Eid', 'PERSON'), ('is', 'O'), ('studying', 'O'), ('at', 'O'), ('Stony', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('Brook', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('University', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('in', 'O'), ('NY', 'O')]
> ```

For `CoreNLPNERTagger` you should first start a core NLP server and connect to it like this:

```
with CoreNLPServer(port=9000) as server:
    tagger = CoreNLPNERTagger(url=server.url)
    tagger.tag(...)
```

Or simply use `StanfordPOSTagger` the same way you're currently trying.